# How to run class files from jar file, where class files are in bin filder

Tags: java, eclipse, class, exception, bin

I have used the command `jar -cvf myjar.jar javaproject` for the creating jar file of the entire Java project

I am unable to run class file from jar file, I have given like that in command prompt:

```
D:\Automation>java -cp myjar.jar bin.Test.First
```

The following exception is occurred:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: bin/Test
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bin.Test.First
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Metho
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Sourc
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: bin.Test.First.  Program will exit.
```

My project structure like this in Eclipse:

```
javaproject 
  |
  |- src 
     |
     |- package(Test)
        |
        |- First.java
```

Note: class files comes bin folder, while I saved the Test.java file in Eclipse, where src is not the system creation folder, it is created by Eclipse

Comment: Use lowercase for package names: test.First

Answer (score 0):

You need to omit the bin folder. Use

```
jar cvf myjar.jar -C bin .
```

to create the jar file. The `-C` option tells `jar` to go into the specified folder (`bin` in this case) before creating the jar file.

Then use

```
java -cp myjar.jar Test.First
```

to run your application. The `bin` folder is not part of your Java package structure.

Answer (score 0):

You have easiest & alternative way to create a jar in `eclipse IDE`

[See here](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/handouts/Eclipse%20Help/jarInEclipse.htm) and follow those steps and create a jar .

To run, move to the bin folder from command prompt

```
 >java -cp path/to/jar/ classname
```

Answer (score 0):

Add just the contents of the `bin` directory to the JAR. If you are confused, a simple way is to Select the contents of the `bin` directory and add them to a zip archive and change the extension to `jar`. Then you can use

```
java -cp myjar.jar Test.First
```

And since you are using eclipse, just go to

```
File --> Export --> Runnable Jar File
```

This way just use

```
java -jar myjar.jar
```